# Search and replace only on a specific section

Tags: html, language-agnostic

I have a couple of thousands of .html files and I need to search and replace a hardcoded server name to a relative path, but ONLY in the footer.

e.g.

```
<body>
   <a href="http://hardcoded/something">This is ok</a>      
   ... much more content here
   <div class="footer">
       <a href="http://hardcoded/something">Change this one</a>      
   </div>
</body>
```

Is there any tool to do this kind of search and replace?

Comment: Would you accept an answer in Prolog using [DCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar)

Comment: That would be awesome actually

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks. I'm in the mean time looking at Intellj Structural Search and Replace: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

After posting this answer I refined it into a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603328/1243762).
This answer is being left because it has most of the comments, and serves as a stepping stone to the refined code.

---

Complete code:

change.pl

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).

eos([], []).

dcg_change_002(Html) -->
    { Footer_start_tag = "<div class=\"footer\">" },
    anything(Footer_prefix),
    Footer_start_tag, !,
    anything(Anchor_prefix),
    anchor_2(Anchor), !,
    rest_2(Rest), !,
    {
        string_codes(Anchor_prefix,Anchor_prefix_codes),
        string_codes(Anchor,Anchor_codes),
        string_codes(Rest,Rest_codes),
        append(Footer_prefix,Footer_start_tag,Part_1),
        append(Part_1,Anchor_prefix_codes,Part_2),
        append(Part_2,Anchor_codes,Part_3),
        append(Part_3,Rest_codes,Html)
    }.

anything([]) --> [].
anything([C|Cs]) -->
     [C],
     anything(Cs).

rest_2([]) --> call(eos).
rest_2([C|Cs]) -->
    \+ call(eos),
     [C],
     rest_2(Cs).

anchor_2("<a href=\"http://changed/something\">") --> "<a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">".
```

Test case:

```
:- begin_tests(html_dcg).

test(002) :-
    HTML_in = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>",
    Expected_HTML_out = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://changed/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>",
    string_codes(HTML_in,HTML_in_codes),
    DCG = dcg_change_002(HTML_out_codes),
    phrase(DCG,HTML_in_codes,Rest),
    string_codes(HTML_out,HTML_out_codes),
    format('~nHTML: ~n`~w''~n',[HTML_out]),
    assertion( HTML_out == Expected_HTML_out ),
    assertion( Rest == [] ).

:- end_tests(html_dcg).
```

Example run of test:

```
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- consult("C:/change.pl").
true.

?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: html_dcg 
HTML: 
`<body>
   <a href="http://hardcoded/something">This is ok</a>
   <div class="footer">
       <a href="http://changed/something">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>'
. done
% test passed
true.
```

Normally a test would not output a result, e.g. ``` format('~nHTML: ~n``~w''~n',[HTML_out]) ``` but it was added so you could see the result without the boilerplate code in the test.

Since this one is closer to what should be done here is an explanation.

Prolog is normally written using predicates, they use the operator `:-`. DCGs are different and use `-->`. DCG is translated into regular Prolog, and DCGs can include regular Prolog by using `{ ... }`.

DCGs process character codes, in this case because this is all ASCII text, you can use the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), but trying to read ASCII character list is hard so,

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
```

tells the compiler that anything between `" ... "` is to be converted to a list of character codes.

The test drives this so starting with the test case

```
:- begin_tests(html_dcg).
:- end_tests(html_dcg).
```

set up a test module named `htm_dcg` and

```
test(002) :-
```

have a test predicate named `002`.

```
HTML_in = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>"
```

This uses [=/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2) (unification), which is not assignment, to bind the HTML text to the variable `HTML_in` but since this is a separate module than the code it is a string and not converted to a list of character codes. The `\c` is an [escape character](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=charescapes) that allows `<body>` to be begin on the next line without adding `\n` to the input. Also `"` have to be escaped for Prolog as `\"`.

```
Expected_HTML_out = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://changed/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>"
```

Ditto for `Expected_HTML_out`.

Since the DCG wants codes, convert the string to codes with

```
string_codes(HTML_in,HTML_in_codes)
```

In reality the next two lines would be written as one

```
phrase(dcg_change_002(HTML_out_codes),HTML_in_codes,Rest)
```

but that is a bit long and confusing.

[phrase/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase/3) is what transitions from predicates to DCGs and why I explicitly in this example write the next two lines as

```
DCG = dcg_change_002(HTML_out_codes),
phrase(DCG,HTML_in_codes,Rest)
```

so that you can see that `dcg_change_002/2` is a DCG and it will return the HTML result. It is named with `codes` to show that it comes back as a list of character codes and not a string. `Rest` is over kill but used to catch some rare errors working with

```
 assertion( Rest == [] )
```

Since the HTML comes back as a list of character codes, it is converted back to a string with

```
string_codes(HTML_out,HTML_out_codes)
```

so that it can be used with

```
format('~nHTML: ~n`~w''~n',[HTML_out])
```

to print out the HTML for demonstration of valid working and

```
assertion( HTML_out == Expected_HTML_out )
```

to show that the code returns the expected result.

As for the DCG, the entry point is

```
dcg_change_002(Html) -->
```

and to demonstrate that text can be used as a pattern that can be matched

```
{ Footer_start_tag = "<div class=\"footer\">" }
```

So the problem is to grab all of the text up to the `Footer_start_tag` and that is done with

```
anything(Footer_prefix)
```

then match on the `Footer_start_tag`

```
Footer_start_tag, !,
```

The `!` is to stop backtracking and is too advanced for this discussion, but improves performance, but its use is frowned upon in purity circles, (long discussion, don't ask).

```
anything(Anchor_prefix)
```

Now that we are in the footer grab all of the text up to `Anchor`.

```
    anchor_2(Anchor), !,
```

Here `Anchor` is in

```
anchor_2("<a href=\"http://changed/something\">") -->  
    "<a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">".
```

which matches on the code you want to replace

```
"<a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">".
```

and return the code you want to change it to

```
 "<a href=\"http://changed/something\">"
```

You can actually make a table of these rules and change out multiple matches like this anchor all at once if you want for the same location in the input,

and finally grab the rest of the text.

```
rest_2(Rest), !,
```

Now for the part of the code I am still not happy with.

Since it is all within `{ ... }` it is not DCG but regular Prolog embedded in DCG.

```
{

    string_codes(Anchor_prefix,Anchor_prefix_codes),
    string_codes(Anchor,Anchor_codes),
    string_codes(Rest,Rest_codes),
```

which are more conversions of string to codes.

```
    append(Footer_prefix,Footer_start_tag,Part_1),
    append(Part_1,Anchor_prefix_codes,Part_2),
    append(Part_2,Anchor_codes,Part_3),
    append(Part_3,Rest_codes,Html)
```

which append all of the character list back together into one list and bind the variable `HTML` with the result.

```
}.
```

The `}` just exits the embedded code.

```
anything([]) --> [].
anything([C|Cs]) -->
     [C],
     anything(Cs).
```

Is a standard recursive call that just grabs individual characters `C` and build them into a list using `|`.

```
rest_2([]) --> call(eos).
rest_2([C|Cs]) -->
    \+ call(eos),
     [C],
     rest_2(Cs).
```

Another standard recursive call that just grabs individual characters `C` and build them into a list using `|` but this one is looking for the `End Of Stream` thus `eos`. The `\+` is the Prolog way of doing not.

I know for many if not most who read this, this looks way to simple, but in reality it should be that simple. The reason you don't see or hear more programmers doing this is that learning Logic Programming, e.g. Prolog, is hard and even then many classes on Prolog never get near DCGs. It took me years to get to this level and even then by most standards this code is not that great, it will get the job done, and is fast to write and quite versatile.

I hope to post another more advanced and simpler version, but truthfully this is the first time I tried using DCGs with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes). 

dcg_change_004(Html) -->
    string(Footer_prefix_codes),
    { Footer_start_tag_codes = "<div class=\"footer\">" },
    Footer_start_tag_codes,
    string(Anchor_prefix_codes),
    anchor(Anchor_codes),
    remainder(Rest_codes), !,
    {
        flatten([Footer_prefix_codes,Footer_start_tag_codes,Anchor_prefix_codes,Anchor_codes,Rest_codes],Codes),
        string_codes(Html,Codes)
    }.

anchor("<a href=\"http://changed/something\">") -->  
  "<a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">".
```

Yes the code is really that small !!!

---

This works by thinking of the HMTL as a stream of characters and not as a structure such as a [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) or [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) which greatly simplifies the problem. This technique can not be used in all cases but is sufficient for the problem as posed in this question.

For more detail on limitations of this techniques see [this](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/interesting-stackoverflow-question-on-replacing-text-in-html-looking-for-better-way-to-do-this/514/6).

Two of the clauses used in this [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601099/1243762), `anything//1` and `rest_2//1` can be replaced with with clauses from a library.

[basics.pl -- Various general DCG utilities](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl)

The library is added to this with

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
```

---

How the code works:

Read everything up to `<div class="footer">`

```
string(Footer_prefix_codes),
{ Footer_start_tag_codes = "<div class=\"footer\">" },
Footer_start_tag_codes
```

Note: `"<div class=\"footer\">"`  is bound to a variable because it is needed twice, once for matching the input and once as part of the output. By placing it in a variable it doesn't have to be typed twice.

then 
read everything up to `<a href="http://hardcoded/something">`

```
string(Anchor_prefix_codes)
```

and replace it with `<a href="http://changed/something">`

```
anchor(Anchor_codes)
```

which works with

```
anchor("<a href=\"http://changed/something\">") -->  
  "<a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">".
```

then 
read everything remaining.

```
remainder(Rest_codes)
```

Along the way the DCG collected the character codes into list,

```
Footer_prefix_codes
Footer_start_tag_codes
Anchor_prefix_codes
Anchor_codes
Rest_codes
```

These are flattened into one list using

```
flatten([Footer_prefix_codes,Footer_start_tag_codes,Anchor_prefix_codes,Anchor_codes,Rest_codes],Codes)
```

and the list of character codes `Codes` is converted to a string with

```
string_codes(Html,Codes)
```

with `Html` being the result.

Here is the test case

```
:- begin_tests(html_dcg).

test(004) :-
    HTML_in = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>",
    Expected_HTML_out = "\c
<body>
   <a href=\"http://hardcoded/something\">This is ok</a>
   <div class=\"footer\">
       <a href=\"http://changed/something\">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>",
    string_codes(HTML_in,HTML_in_codes),
    DCG = dcg_change_004(HTML_out),
    phrase(DCG,HTML_in_codes,Rest),
    format('~nHTML: ~n`~w''~n',[HTML_out]),
    assertion( HTML_out == Expected_HTML_out ),
    assertion( Rest == [] ).

:- end_tests(html_dcg).
```

Example run of test case:

```
?- run_tests(html_dcg:4).
% PL-Unit: html_dcg:4 
HTML: 
`<body>
   <a href="http://hardcoded/something">This is ok</a>
   <div class="footer">
       <a href="http://changed/something">Change this one</a>
   </div>
</body>'
. done
% test passed
true.
```

It is really that simple with DCGs. In some ways DCGs are like BNF and like Regular Expressions; in the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) they are more powerful then Regular Expressions. So if Regular Expression are driving you nuts and you don't want to write lots of boiler plate code with a parser or fight parsing conflict rules with a parser, switch to DCGs.

Enjoy.

---

Prolog code to search directories for files with type `html`.

```
test_01 :-
    Directory = 'C:\\Something',
    process_directory(Directory,[],Items),
    print_paths(Items).

process_directory(Directory,Items0,Items) :-
    directory_files(Directory,Files),
    process_files(Directory,Files,Items0,Items).

process_files(Directory,[File|Files],Items0,Items) :-
    process_file(Directory,File,Items0,Items1),
    process_files(Directory,Files,Items1,Items), !.
process_files(_Directory,[],Items,Items).

process_file(Directory,File,Items0,Items) :-
    (
        File = '.',
        Items = Items0
    ;
        File = '..',
        Items = Items0
    ;
        directory_file_path(Directory, File, Path),
        exists_directory(Path),
        process_directory(Path,Items0,Items1),
        Items = Items1
    ;
        directory_file_path(Directory, File, Path),
        exists_file(Path),
        (
            file_name_extension(_Name, 'html', File),
            Items = [Path|Items0]
        ;
            Items = Items0
        )
    ;
        Items = Items0
    ).

print_paths([Path|Paths]) :-
    format('~w~n',Path),
    print_paths(Paths).
print_paths([]).
```

---

This section of code I didn't check because of the tedium of making the test data, so check it before using.

Make a backup copies of your directory before using this if you don't know exactly what you are doing. One mistake and it will wipe out all of your files because it is writing many files in many directories.

```
change_footer(Directory) :-
    process_directory(Directory,[],Paths),
    print_paths(Paths),
    change_files(Paths).

change_files([Path|Paths]) :-
    open(Path,write,Stream),
    read_stream_to_codes(Stream,Codes),
    DCG = dcg_change_004(HTML),
    phrase(DCG,Codes),
    format(Stream,HTML,[]),
    close(Stream),
    change_files(Paths).
change_files([]).
```

Comment: The idea is very clear, unfortunately I couldn't implement it as I don't know prolog and the "read 1,700 files, and write them back" was too daunting for me, I tried and eventually modify that program in Java and it works perfectly (obviously it doesn't look anything similar anymore)

Comment: You should of told me to add the read part. I'll add that soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
package custom;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String startPath = "/Users/me/someProject/public";

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(startPath), new SimpleFileVisitor<>(){
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                if (!path.toString().endsWith(".html")) {
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
                var content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), "UTF-8");

                var fixedContent = replaceAfter(content,
                        "<div class=\"footer\">",
                        "http://hardcoded/something",
                        "/something");

                Files.write(path, fixedContent.getBytes());
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the `searchTerm` with `replacement` but only after the ocurrence of `afterMark`
     * If `afterMark` is not present nothing is changed
     * @param source - Original string
     * @param afterMark - Will perform the replacement after this mark is found
     * @param searchTerm - What to replace
     * @param replacement - replacement
     * @return a new string with the search term replaced
     */
    public static String replaceAfter(String source, String afterMark, String searchTerm, String replacement) {
        var i = source.indexOf(afterMark);
        if ( i < 0 ) {
            return source;
        }
        var replaced = source.substring(i).replace(searchTerm, replacement);
        return source.substring(0, i) + replaced;
    }
}
```